# How does one access the current id sequence value in the activerecord initializer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I'm building an activerecord to model a conversation tree, using an array column type to represent the materialized path of the record's place in that tree, using postgres 9.1, rails 4.0, and the pg gem.

What I really want to do is access currval('conversations_id_seq') when I create a new conversation object, so that I can pass in [grandparent_id, parent_id ... current_id] as the array to the object initializer. That way I can specify that this column is not null as a database constraint, and in the event of a parentless conversation, have it still default to [current_id].

The problem I have is getting access to the model's id value before I save it the first time. I could always relax the not null constraint and add an after_create hook, but that feels kludgy. I'm hopeful that there's a way I can grab the value that's getting pushed into @id inside the initializer, before the first save to the database.

EDIT to clarify for the bounty: In an ideal world, there would be a special token I could pass in to the object's create method: Conversation.create(reply_chain: [:lastval]), where the  gem took that to mean lastval() in the generated SQL.

Comment: An empty path array might make more sense than a self-referential path array for root nodes, then the paths become `parent.path + [parent.id]` and the sequence problem goes away.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

something like:

```
def before_create
   self.id=Conversation.connection.execute("SELECT nextval('conversations_id_seq')")
   self.path = [... , self.id];
   true
end
```

or use a before insert/update trigger to maintain the path.

Comment: Aha! Yes, that is clearly the thing I should have done. This more or less works as written (except that connection.execute returns a PG::Result that you have to grab the actual int value from). Specs pass and it's still concurrency safe.

Comment: Querieng this `SELECT nextval('conversations_id_seq')` over database assumes that this id is now used and assigns an incremented version to the actual record. Any recommendation on this issue if I have set auto increment on a sequence and assigned it to a column ?

Comment: @M. Habib recommendation: ignore that. In almost all cases you do not care about gaps in sequences

Answer (score 0):

You could alias the attribute if you don't need the column in the database.

```
alias_attribute :current_id, :id
```

Or you could query for the id when you need it.

```
def self.last_val
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("SELECT lastval('conversations_id_seq')")
end

def self.next_val
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("SELECT nextval('conversations_id_seq')")
end

Conversation.create(reply_chain: Conversation.next_val)
```

Using after_save isn't the ugliest of code either.

Comment: Defining the last_val method is similar to what I need, but the timing seems to be off - if I try to call Conversation.create(reply_chain: [Conversation.last_val]), for example, the last_val call will evaluate before the create call.